# Google Sign in button issue

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-openid

I am trying to add the Google Sign in to my application, i am following the official tutorial of Google : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

unfortunately i can't add the google sign in button, i did the same as is described in the document :

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
```

[image: The JS file is loaded]

i try to add the button with this :

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

but nothing happen !

thanks !

Comment: post ur full code on http://jsfiddle.net i will check the complete script once

Comment: @BetaCoder when i execute the code on jsfiddle.net, it works fine, but on my browser i don't see anything !

Comment: might be due to some typo mistakes in html / javascript tag openings or closing

Answer (score 0):

Google sign in button works only when the button is rendered from a web app. The button is not rendered in your case because you might be trying to run it as an HTML file.

What you need to do is render the HTML file from a web app.